# Jquery Sortable Not dragging or dropping list items in django

Tags: jquery, html, django

I am trying to implement Jquery sortable drag and drop from one list to another but I am unable to do so. Below is my code. The error that I am getting is :

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

Please help.
This is what I want to achieve : https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block abc %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
        #sortable1, #sortable2 {
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            width: 142px;
            min-height: 20px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
            margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            width: 120px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
            }).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
    <div class="wrap">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <li id="item_1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li id="item_2" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li id="item_3" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li id="item_4" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li id="item_5" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li id="item_6" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
        <li id="item_7" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
        <li id="item_8" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
        <li id="item_9" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
        <li id="item_10" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What did not work here that you are expecting it to, as the whole source code is there in the link you have mentioned? Can you please explain that part.

Comment: The dragging and dropping isn't working. Only the list is being shown.

Comment: It works for me when I copy you code and saved as html

Comment: It works in normal HTML but not when I include that HTML in my django project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I first of all changed my url from

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also I put it in the beginning of my file and also in the base.html file.